# how to get alert when text area contain change without save change?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am making project on online editor for html like jsfiddle.net

My question is how to get alert when text area contain change without save change?

For example see below image

[image]

Comment: When or in what situation you want to show the alert?

Comment: just make an ajax call to autosave on `keyup`. Those boxes are annoying

Comment: Take a look at the `beforeunload` event. When you make a change, you set a variable, and the `beforeunload` handler checks the variable.

Comment: when user change textarea contain and leave page without save

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload) like,

```
var $formData=$('#myform').serialize(); 
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if($formData!=$('#myform').serialize()){
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you can do it by using `.data()` like,

```
var $myForm=$('#myform');
$myForm.data('initialData',$myForm.serialize());    
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if($myForm.data('initialData') != $myForm.serialize()){
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
    }
};
```